# Drop the [database] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

A lot of the [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) questions have specific database engine tags on them. I think we should stick to the database engine tags instead of the generic [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database).

I think that we should burn the database tag and ask the user to use the specific database engine tag ([sql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql), [nosql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nosql), [mysql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql), etc.)

I just don't think that adding a [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) adds anything to the question. It may only exist for SEO, and if that is the case I think we should set some guidelines on how to use it properly because we definitely need to know the specific engine being used in the code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What if someone has us reviewing their custom database software? (Aside from closing as TOO MUCH COOOODE)

Comment: I can't think of anything that a more specific tag wouldn't cover. I don't think this one can stand on its own feet.

Comment: Oi! That's a lot of questions. Maybe a synonym with [tag:sql] is a better course of action?

Comment: do all databases use a Structured Query Language(SQL)?

Comment: Good question! I don't know. Technically, no. A database can be as simple as a text file and looking at the questions makes me think that just creating a synonym would be a bad idea.

Comment: I was wondering why there suddenly were so many items in the review queue, plenty of them merely removing this tag. And I'm not even getting points for approving all those edits... ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually follow this tag, so I figured I would take the opportunity to chime in a bit.

I wrote a little [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/322247/database-tag-posts-with-other-non-dbms-tags) to find what *other* tags are being used along with [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database), besides the usual SQL and NoSQL culprits.

I have not spent that much time looking at each one individually, but apparently either some of them are mis-tagged with [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database), or there is an evident desire for a database tag that does not have anything to do with DBMS's.

My opinion would be keep it, but perhaps clean it up. Anything tagged with `'%sql%'` is obviously database, so that tag would be redundant. Same with other DBMS types, such as the NoSQL [mongodb](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) so there could safely be removed. I think anything outside those should keep the tag if it is appropriate.

Comment: I don't agree that being tagged with anything SQL-related inherently makes [database] a redundant tag.  [Just because you're writing SQL, doesn't mean you're *actually* using a database](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56875/fizzbuzz-in-sql-no-loops). And furthermore, [there are questions about SQL that aren't about databases](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59308/36366). Admittedly, that one isn't tagged [sql], but it easily could be.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen many posts using [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) in combination with [mysql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [sql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql), [oracle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle) and [postresql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postresql).

If [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) is used in combination with multiple other database tags, it's superfluous. I've started removing the obvious superfluous ones, since they don't add any relevant information.

It's like putting [oop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop) on every [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23), or [iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iteration) on anything with a `for` loop. Sometimes tags don't bring any new (relevant) information.

Comment: `Removed superfluous [tag:database]. Implicitly mentioned by other tags.`

Comment: I was going to do that...now what am I supposed to do at work all day?

Comment: @Lyle'sMug [Nuke zombies?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22001121#22001121)

Comment: young Padawan, quoting masters already.  lol

Answer (score 8):

The [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) should not be eliminated.  There are database-related questions beyond just SQL and variants of it.  Examples:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93389/adding-database-related-functions-while-using-wordpress
- [Looking up the name and event for a ticket](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/looking-up-the-name-and-event-for-a-ticket)
- [Building a simple database in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30785/building-a-simple-database-in-python)
- [Auto-expire key/value database (with different key types) in Haskell using acid-state](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78392/auto-expire-key-value-database-with-different-key-types-in-haskell-using-acid)

It's not necessarily doing harm for a question to have a [database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) tag, as long as it doesn't crowd out other better tags.  I wouldn't even make a special effort to retag old questions, except when doing opportunistic retagging while making other improvements.

Comment: Good point, I think that that your answer is a twist on Phrancis's answer, where you are saying don't worry about retagging unless you are already there for another reason. thank you for the good advice!